# Why is my BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray returning null?

Tags: android, android-bitmap

I am trying to convert an image stored in Database in Base64 format, to a Bitmap to be used in an Imageview.

So, I store it in SQLite this way:

```
Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Bitmap fotoGrande=(Bitmap) extras.get("data");
imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
//I am adding some data to EXIF here, add to an static ArrayList<Bitmap> in other class and I store it this way:

int bytes=listaFotos.get(i).getFoto().getByteCount();
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bytes);
listaFotos.get(i).getFoto().copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer);
values.put("foto", Base64.encodeToString(buffer.array(), Base64.DEFAULT));
```

Later, i need to get that image to fit it in an ImageView:

```
String foto = csr2.getString(0);//csr2 is a cursor
byte[] arrayFoto = Base64.decode(foto, Base64.DEFAULT);//This is not null
Bitmap fotoBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(arrayFoto, 0, arrayFoto.length);//This is null
```

I know there are tons of questions about this. I searched, but no answer fix my problem.

Why is my BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray returning null? What I am doing wrong? Any help?

Thank you.

Comment: it returns null if the image could not be decoded.

Comment: Yeah, I know that, I read the doc, I would like to know why the image could not be decoded.

Comment: Probably because memory to do so run out. Take a very small image and you will see that it decodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out to be a database issue. SQLite gives you a cursor of 1MB MAX size. I was getting the bytes from database, with a 1MB cursor, the pic was not sent properly.

To fix it, I stored the path to the photo in database instead of the bytes.

Answer (score 0):

firstly image is convert in `Bitmap` to `String`  like this

```
 ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        camera.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
        byte imageInByte[] = stream.toByteArray();
        String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageInByte, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

where `camera` is a Bitmap.
and store the String `encodedImage`  in database

And getImage string like this

```
 byte[] b = Base64.decode(encodedImage , Base64.DEFAULT);
        Bitmap  bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b, 0, b.length);
```

Comment: More or less...is the same thing I am doing. Anyway, my question is when I receive the data from database, not when I store it. I store it  without any problem.

Comment: then check when get data in data base data is not null.

Comment: Then check some other problem, because this code is run and return bitmap successful.

Comment: That is why im getting mad, that code should work...I am compressing it to JPEG before storing in database. Maybe should I "decompress" it? I thing JPEG is supported by Android, but maybe I have to convert it to a regular Bitmap...?

Comment: please check when you store the image in data base.. because you get image in right way..

Comment: It's in the question, I am encoding it to Base64 before I store it, and definitely it stores something. When i get it from database, I am receiving the Base64 String, debugging I have seen it is not null. But the BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray returns null.

Comment: I Think when you convert and store the image then its not convert in proper way in string..